# it's possible how we can put value in kivy file and return value to py file.and deal with it

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I will write simple code to understanding better , imagine we have 3 Button in kivy file like bellow code

kivy file:

```
Button:
   text: A1
   variable = 3
Button:
   text : A2
   variable = 2
Button:
   text :A3
   variable = 3
```

how I can put variable in kivy file when I prese on each button the variable change according value we defined, then deal with varable in python file

py file

```
def btn(self):
    new_variable= variable+5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  use a text input :

kivi

```
Label:
   id:label
   text:'here is displayed the final result'

#here you insert content of variable
TextInput:
    id: txt_inpt
    text: '' 
    font_size:16

Button:
    text: 'A1'
    on_press: root.func()
```

Python:

```
def func():
    var= self.ids.txt_inpt.text
    addvar = int(var) + 5
    self.ids.label.text = str(addvar)
```